# Angular 5 make local variable to global

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a code like this :

```
var data = [
   {
     first_name: "Apurv",
     date: "2018-01-22",
     is_present: "1", 
   },
   {
     first_name: "Lucky",
     date: "2018-01-22",
     is_present: "0", 
   },
   {
     first_name: "Apurv",
     date: "2018-01-20",
     is_present: "0", 
   },
   {
     first_name: "Lucky",
     date: "2018-01-20",
     is_present: "1", 
   }
];

var groupByName = {};

data.forEach(function (a) {
    groupByName [a.first_name] = groupByName [a.first_name] || [];
    groupByName [a.first_name].push({ date: a.date, is_present: a.is_present });
});

console.log(groupByName);
```

I try to make local variable of `groupByName` variable become global in order to works with *ngIf on Angular 5, could everyone clearing this or maybe there is another way to solve this issue? I would be thank you before!

Comment: Not sure I got what you are trying to do. But I would make it a property of your component class.

Comment: I just want to make looping from groupByName variable but the variable is in local, I try to make it global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it as a property of your component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mycomponent',
  template: '<some html here>',
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{

  public data:any[];
  public groupByName:any;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = [
       {
         first_name: "Apurv",
         date: "2018-01-22",
         is_present: "1", 
       },
       {
         first_name: "Lucky",
         date: "2018-01-22",
         is_present: "0", 
       },
       {
         first_name: "Apurv",
         date: "2018-01-20",
         is_present: "0", 
       },
       {
         first_name: "Lucky",
         date: "2018-01-20",
         is_present: "1", 
       }
    ];

    this.groupByName = {};

    this.data.forEach(function (a) {
        this.groupByName[a.first_name] = this.groupByName [a.first_name] || [];
        this.groupByName[a.first_name].push({ date: a.date, is_present: a.is_present });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, copy/paste error. Forgot *this* at "data.foreach...". - just corrected my solution

Comment: yeah, I've trying as you explained above but this.groupByName is undefined, I don't know why as before I've trying using return this.groupByName but the result is still undefined. Maybe you know the way how to groupping by JSON data by each categories, I would be thank you for your response.

Comment: I checked your routine and the result is OK:
{ Apurv:
   [ { date: '2018-01-22', is_present: '1' },
     { date: '2018-01-20', is_present: '0' } ],
  Lucky:
   [ { date: '2018-01-22', is_present: '0' },
     { date: '2018-01-20', is_present: '1' } ] }

Must be another problem! Could you please post your exact error message ?

Comment: Thanks, unexpectedly it works after I re-run the ionic serve command, maybe livereload won't reload the browser properly. Well, I say thank you for solving this.